# Deseo fijar el ultimo widget de mi sidebar pero solo debe ser visible en el momento en que se vuelva fijo

Tags: jquery, revisión-de-código

Hola que tal estoy trabajando con una plantilla en wordpress y este es mi problema al crear un ultimo widget en mi sidebar el queda fijo asi que le di la propiedad de visibility:hidden asi

```
   div#ad_widget_sizes_exm1-19 .ad-widget-sizes {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

aquí les dejo la pagina si la desean visualizar por ahora solo debería funcionar con los posts http://cci.woobsing.co/innovacion-estructuras-cundinamarca/

y para que funcionara hice un pequeño script pero al momento de ejecutar se mantiene visibility:hidden se que no es problema de jquery pues he metido un monton agradezco cualquier ayuda

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var ity = jQuery.noConflict();
  if(ity(".home-widget .one-part .navigation-has-menu").hasClass(".fixed-widget")){
    console.log("ERROR");
    ity("div#ad_widget_sizes_exm1-19 .ad-widget-sizes").css("visibility", "visible");
}

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Existe un error en el selector `ity(".home-widget .one-part .navigation-has-menu")`, el mismo así como esta devuelve vació, es decir, **no existe un elemento cumpla con esta regla**.

En cambio si lo escribo sin espacios, así:

```
ity(".home-widget.one-part.navigation-has-menu")
```

Devuelve exactamente 1 elemento.
Este selector se traduce a: **buscar los elementos que tengan las clases `home-widget, one-part y navigation-has-menu`.**

Comment: gracias al final lo deje mejor que apareciera según la distancia recorrida por el scroll porque nunca reconoció la clase fixed widget